# Extract numbers before period in a text field in R

Tags: r, regex, text

I'm trying to extract numbers before a period for the following texts

question1="1.10.1.1.Describe this process"

question2="1.10.1. Describe this process that takes 30 days"

So the following does the trick but it also returns the period, how do I get rid of the period?

str_extract_all(question1,"[0-9]+\.")

str_extract_all(question2,"[0-9]+\.")

Comment: `str_extract_all(question1,"[0-9]+(?=\\.)")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `sub` from `base R` to match the `.` followed by zero or more space (`\\s*`) followed by one or more letters and other characters (`.*`) and in the replacement specify blank (`""`) and pass that input in `read.table` to create data.frame

```
read.table(text = sub("\\.\\s*[A-Za-z]+.*", "", txt),
      header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, sep=".")
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  1 10  1  1
#2  1 10  1 NA
```

#### data

```
txt <- c("1.10.1.1.Describe this process", 
        "1.10.1. Describe this process that takes 30 days")
```

Comment: I want to extract them separately and put them into separate columns; so for question 1, I want to extract 1 10 1 1 and each of these will go to separate columns. And for question 2, I want to extract 1 10 1

Comment: @Melika Updated the post

Answer (score 0):

You may use a lookahead in your regex:

```
str_extract_all(question1,"[0-9]+(?=\\.)")
                                 ^^^^^^^
```

The `(?=\.)` matches a location immediately followed with a dot. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o7o0Jm/1).

See [R demo](https://rextester.com/OYLZ33024):

```
library(stringr)
question1="1.10.1.1.Describe this process"
str_extract_all(question1,"[0-9]+(?=\\.)")
## [[1]]
## [1] "1"  "10" "1"  "1" 
question2="1.10.1. Describe this process that takes 30 days"
str_extract_all(question2,"[0-9]+(?=\\.)")
## [[1]]
## [1] "1"  "10" "1"
```

Comment: How do I use str_extract_all to create new columns?

Comment: I want to extract them separately and put them into separate columns; so for question1, I want to extract 1 10 1 1 and each of these will go to separate columns. And for question 2, I want to extract 1 10 1.

Comment: @Mel If there can be 1 to 4 numbers, use `str_match(question1,"^(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+))?(?:\\.(\\d+))?(?:\\.(\\d+))?")`, see https://rextester.com/YKWDZ16180